# Скрытие и показ заголовоков в разных состояниях страницы - реакция поисковиков?

Tags: seo, html, css

Все мы знаем, что поисковики плохо реагируют на скрытый контент страницы. Знаем, что за предоставление разной информации пользователям и поисковикам можно получить бан. Но это в общем. Когда дело доходит до деталей я начинаю сомневаться. Прошу рекомендаций :)

**Вопрос**

Адаптивный дизайн. На странице несколько заголовков.

```
<h1>Primary Header</h1>
<h2>Secondary header</h2>
<h2>Secondary header</h2>
...
<h2>Secondary header</h2>
...
```

Часть из них изначально скрыта (например последний h2 через display:none в CSS). Но в разных ситуация (зависит от ширины страницы, dpi устройства и т.д.) display: none заменяется на display: block (медиа запросом) для одних заголовков, и наоборот для других.

Получается размытая ситуация :)
Насколько это адекватно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используете **html5**, то можно попробовать объединить заголовки в группу [< hgroup >](http://htmlbook.ru/html/hgroup). Могу предположить, что в этом случае они будут считаться одним целым и пропускаться некоторая несостыковка.

Comment: Хорошая идея, спасибо!
В половине случаев (когда заголовки идут друг за другом) это будет даже по коду логичней.